# Append data dynamically to my xml SOAP message

Tags: python, xml, string, soap

I am calling an API by sending an xml request by doing a string formatting  like this:

```
data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
         <SOAP-ENV:Body>
             <ns2:MultiAvailabilityRequest xmlns:m="http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway" Password="CoolJoe" Token="{token}" UserName="CoolJoe"> 
         <ns2:MultiAvailabilityCriteria NumberOfUnits="{units}">
         <ns2:StayDateRange CheckIn="2016-05-02" CheckOut="2016-05-04"/> 
         <ns2:GuestCounts>
           <ns2:GuestCount AdultCount="{adultcount}"/>
           </ns2:GuestCounts> 
         <ns2:HotelCodes>
           <ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode}</ns2:HotelCode> 
         </ns2:HotelCodes>
         </ns2:MultiAvailabilityCriteria>
      </ns2::MultiAvailabilityRequest>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
     </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''.format(token=token, units=units, adultcount=adultcount, hotelcode=hotelcode)
```

The above code is working fine and getting the value of different hotelcodes, token etc and showing the results based on them.

But, I have one more different requirement where the hotelcodes could be more than 1 (either 2,3 or more). And, the required xml will look like this:

```
data = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
         <SOAP-ENV:Body>
             <ns2:MultiAvailabilityRequest xmlns:m="http://www.derbysoft.com/doorway" Password="CoolJoe" Token="{token}" UserName="CoolJoe"> 
         <ns2:MultiAvailabilityCriteria NumberOfUnits="{units}">
         <ns2:StayDateRange CheckIn="2016-05-02" CheckOut="2016-05-04"/> 
         <ns2:GuestCounts>
           <ns2:GuestCount AdultCount="{adultcount}"/>
           </ns2:GuestCounts> 
         <ns2:HotelCodes>
           <ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode1}</ns2:HotelCode>
           <ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode2}</ns2:HotelCode> 
           <ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode3}</ns2:HotelCode>  
         </ns2:HotelCodes>
         </ns2:MultiAvailabilityCriteria>
      </ns2::MultiAvailabilityRequest>
     </SOAP-ENV:Body>
     </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'''.format(token=token, units=units, adultcount=adultcount)
```

So, my question is: how do I check whether two hotelcodes are present or more than two. As you can see from second xml for each hotel code, a new line like this adds up:

```
<ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode1}</ns2:HotelCode>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should split the process in two parts:

1. fill in the hotel codes (doesn't really matter if it's one or more):

   `hotelcode_string =''.join(['<ns2:HotelCode>{hotelcode}</ns2:HotelCode>'.format(hotelcode=code) for code in set([item["hotelcode"] for item in hotelcode])])`
2. put the hotel code section in the xml:

   `data = '''.... <ns2:HotelCodes>{hotelcode_string}</ns2:HotelCodes>
        ...'''.format(token=token, units=units, adultcount=adultcount,hotelcode_string=hotelcode_string)`

Comment: can you edit your answer to make in a proper coding format. Point 1 is bit confusing to understand as everything is showing up in one line...

Comment: sorry, for some reason my browser keeps refusing to format this correctly. hope it's a bit more visible now.

Comment: thanks..it's clear now...just want to know, the use of hotelcodes = set(hotel_codes) in point 1. Is it like description, you want to write for below join code?

Comment: converted this to a one-liner, because it's clearer. Basically hotel_codes can be either a single code or a list of codes. By converting it to a set we are doing two things: making it an iterable (in case it's just one value) and making each value unique (in case it's a list where we might have multiple times the same code).

Comment: I still  want to understand this: format(hotelcode=code) for code in set(hotel_codes)? hotel_codes is not defined anywhere? My hotel codes will be coming in this format: hotelcode = [{'hotelcode': 'HY_LONGE'}, {'hotelcode': 'HY_CHIRC'}]

Comment: Edited with a response as per your comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110734/discussion-between-lesingerouge-and-raman-balyan).